# Creating multiple entities with one form using collection type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

so I tried creating a form that can create multiple entities in one form.
The goal is simply by using collection type I can create multiple entities with similar attributes.
The view works where I can add new positions to create more "artikels".
Unfortunately I do not receive any Data if I use $form['artikelList']->getData(). I only receive an empty array(0) but when using $form->getData() I do see the informations on the "artikels".
Can you help me how I can access that data? Googling around did not really help in this regard.

My MultipleFormType file:

```
 /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('artikelList', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ArtikelEmbeddedFormType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false
            ],
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'label' => false,
        ])
        ->add('Speichern', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn--red']
        ]);
}
```

My embeddedFormType file:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ...some entries
        ->add('artikelName', null,
            ['label' => 'Name', 'attr' => ['pattern' => '[A-Za-z0-9-_ öÖäÄüÜß]+', 'maxlength' => 255]])
        ->add('artikelActive', null,
            ['label' => 'Aktiv']);
}
```

And here my controller:

```
 public function createMultipleArtikel(Request $request)
{
    //creating multiple articles at once

    $form = $this->createForm(MultipleArtikelFormType::class, null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        var_dump($form->getData());
        var_dump($form->get('artikelList')->getData());

        foreach($form->get('artikelList')->getData() as $artikel) {
            $this->artikelRepository->update($artikel);
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',
                'done!'
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should check Symfony doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html . You will have to adapt a little bit but you will be able to do what you want

Comment: Hi I read through it and it semed like I have to create a new entity lets call it mulitpleArtikel to work with this. It also requires me to save that specific entity into a database to read the collection, which I do not want, as I just want a way to create multiple articles at once without saving anything extra.

Comment: nvm it worked without saving the multiplearticle entity to any db. Thanks